# A viable alternative to MIDI?

Tags: java, android, api, midi

I'm working on a musical application that relies entirely on MIDI. I want this app to be around for quite awhile, into the next many OS editions, etc. (given normal upkeep and updates, etc.)

But since Microsoft, Java/Google/Android and others are showing signs of dropping MIDI support entirely from their APIs (at least the way I see it) maybe there is a movement to kill MIDI off...?

Anyway, I'm looking for a viable alternative to MIDI with its easy real-time interactivity. I hope to stay with MIDI but if the writing is on the wall I'd rather know now than wait. If MIDI weren't available, what would you do?

Comment: @Ross: Open Sound Control looks very interesting. It will get a good chunk of my time today. But it doesn't necessarily replace MIDI as much as stand in for it, at least the way I read the home page. There must be a technological leap away from MIDI, doesn't there? If we can't access synthesizers through MIDI or OSC, what do we do? That is the question I'm trying to ask. What if we have to do real interactivity with DSP? Or some other hardware? I don't know hardware... I only know a bit of MIDI and c++.

Answer (score 6):

> But since Microsoft, Java/Google/Android and others are showing signs of dropping MIDI support entirely from their APIs (at least the way I see it) maybe there is a movement to kill MIDI off...?

Where did you get this idea? MIDI isn't going anywhere, as it's so simple and universal. If you build an app using MIDI, it's definitely not in danger of becoming obsolete for that reason.

Comment: I don't see a trend towards supporting it in software so I wonder if there is going to be a lack of support in hardware. That's my concern. And if there is we need to find some other way to create musical applications. So I'm trying to figure out if there is already an alternative that I don't know about and that I should be considering.

Comment: @devdon, I don't see why you think MIDI is going away.  It definitely isn't, and if you want to support something that has the most support outside of your application, MIDI is the way to go now, and in the future.

Comment: @Brad, you are most probably right. I'm just interested in two things: why there is (for the moment) decreasing support for such a common standard and what might replace it digitally if it goes away.

Comment: @devdon, I see no evidence that there is decreasing support.  Care to cite some sources?  Also, MIDI is digital...

Comment: @Brad, Microsoft took the midimapper and other higher level things out awhile back, the audio apis now are changing again and I don't know what support win8 will have. Google had midi support in their android/java api and took it out. Why? ow, I'm not panicking or anything but I wonder if they know something that we don't.. and BTW MIDI is serial and not "digital" as in Digital Signal Processing like a sampled audio file, that's what I meant. If we don't have the old MIDI serial access to an onboard chip synth, what will we have and how will we make samples or ??? as effective as MIDI?

Comment: @devdon, You're reading into things.  I can't speak to why MS got rid of the MIDI Mapper, but never has been necessary.  It is my understanding that Google removed the base classes for MIDI playback due to poor support on the hardware side, or software synth drivers.  That doesn't mean you can't use MIDI on Android.  Worst case scenario, on any OS or device, MIDI is very easy to implement from scratch.  There's not exactly a lot to it.